# How to translate in API v2?

Tags: api, localisation

I have extended the Magento v2 API and want to return some translated strings. The only thing that is returned, are the original strings.

To test the translation, I also added the strings to the frontend, it worked.

```
    foreach (Mage::helper('mb-rentalapp')->getInterfaceStrings() as $interface_string)
    {
      echo $interface_string . '::' . Mage::helper('mb-rentalapp')->__($interface_string) . '</br>' ;
    }
```

In the API, I added the following to the response.

```
Mage::helper('mb-rentalapp')->__($interface_string)
```

After some debugging, I noticed that the Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element returned

```
Mage_Core_Model_Translate->getModulesConfig()
```

is populated in frontend, but completely empy in the API v2.

Before adding the translation in the response, I also ran:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeView->getId());
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init()->setLocale($storeView->getConfig('general/locale/code'));
```

Is it even possible to translate in the Magento v2 API?

Answer (score 3):

As Alan mentioned above, the API runs with storeId 0. So I guess if you run `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeView->getId());` you translate with storeId 0 also (btw: where do you get `$storeView` from?).

If you extended the API, you might also add a seperate function or a store view/id parameter to your functions to translate the strings in the store view language you want.

This might be interesting for you to have a look at:

- [get/set current store view for categories](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.currentStore.html)
- [get/set current store view for products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.currentStore.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've never run into this specifically, but I do know the API runs with a store id of `0` by default, which means any configuration or locale settings you grab will be for the admin console.  I'd check the values you're grabbing from `$storeView->getId()` and `$storeView->getConfig('general/locale/code')`, as well as retrace the code with the fact Magento's running in a "not admin but zero store id" state during API requests.

Comment: For now, I've settled with no translations. Best option is probably trying to find out why there are no translate csv files in the config array.

Answer (score 1):

You should run this line at some point point before your translation is needed :

```
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init($area, true);
```

$area should contain the area from which to load transation. If your module `config.xml` has the `<translate>` key inside `<adminhtml>` for example, put `adminhtml` in it.

Set the second param to true to force Magento to reload translation (aka not use cache).

Worked for me.